# About static data members.

Tags: c++, static-members

This is my header file but I don't understand the functionality of static data members if I declared them private or public the output remains same. How static data members work.

```
class cDate        

{

private:

int day;       
int month;  
int year;   
bool valid;   
bool validate();   
bool IsLeapYear() const;   
**static char strMON[12][4];   
static char strMONTH[12][10];**

public:   

cDate(int d = 1, int m = 1, int y = 2000);
cDate(cDate & src);
~cDate();
void print(int option) const;
void ReadFromKB();


void setDay(int d);
void setMonth(int m);
void setYear(int y);
void setDate(int d, int m, int y);


int getDay() const;
int getMonth() const;
int getYear() const;
};
```

Comment: Some guidance: use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays and pointers; use `std::string` instead of arrays of `char`; consider changing the naming conventions so that client code reads nicely (using just `day()`) instead of implementation code that reads nicely.

Comment: For Code That Does Not Work, do present a complete but minimal example that readers can try out.

Comment: @Noman Have you tried working with multiple instances of `cDate` at once?

Comment: Helpful reading material: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static.

Comment: I have implementation file which contain the implementation of all the functions but my question is just about static data members that if i declared them as public or may be private there is no effect on my output. it remains same why?

Comment: You didn't show any code that does any output. Please show that code or rewrite the question without referring to it.

Answer (score 0):

static data are class variable not instance variable;it has nothing to do with modifier

For example

```
class ABC {
static int a;
int b;
}
```

now create two object of class A and assign value

ABC a1= new ABC();
 ABC b1 = new ABC();

so in this case both a1 and b1 have same copy of 'a' because it belongs to class and sharable , so any change by a1 to 'a' variable will reflect change in b1 object also and vice verse.

Comment: means if i declare them as public or may be private there is no effect. because static data are class variables so all members of class access them or there is same copy for all of object.

Comment: @Noman - There is still an 'effect' of declaring public or private ... to any code which is not part of an ABC object.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a data member of a class as static it means that no matter how many objects of the class are created, there is only one copy of the static member. It will be shared by all the objects of the class.